# Splat operator or regex not working?

Tags: ruby, regex, splat

I'm new to Ruby and building Chess as a learning exercise. I'm attempting to refactor some code, and I'm stymied.

Why does this work:

```
@available_moves = []

#part of castling logic
@available_moves << "c1" if empty?("b1") && empty?("c1") && empty?("d1")

def empty?(position)
  get_space(position).token =~ /_/
end
# sample tokens: "_e4", "ka2", "_b3"
```

...and this doesn't?:

```
@available_moves = []

@available_moves << "c1" if emptyii?("b1", "c1", "d1")

def emptyii?(*positions)
  positions.each { |position| get_space(position).token =~ /_/ }
end
```

It's probably something pretty stupid, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `each`, use `all?` to test that all positions return true:

```
positions.all? { |position| get_space(position).token =~ /_/ }
```

`positions.all?` will only be true if the block returns true for each of the positions.

Comment: That's the one. That said, I'm not sure I completely understand why each doesn't work... I guess I'll have to noodle on it a bit.

Comment: The return value of the each method is the list it is iterating over. So the return value of that method call is `["b1", "c1", "d1"]`

Comment: Which means that `if emptyii?` would always be true.

Comment: ...because non-nil/non-false is evaluated as truthy.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are right here in terms of what you need to do, but you should understand why your current solution doesn't work.

You're on the right path, but you simply need to observe your logic in a deeper way. Let's consider the two lines from your code:

```
@available_moves << "c1" if empty?("b1") && empty?("c1") && empty?("d1")
```

This says, "Take c1 and put it into @available_moves IF you get a truth result to b1, c1, and d1 being returned from empty as true. This looks good and clearly works.

However, look at your other line where things break down:

```
@available_moves << "c1" if emptyii?("b1", "c1", "d1")
```

This says, "Shovel c1 into available_moves if...well, what exactly?" Do you consider emptyii true if b1 is true, but c1 and d1 aren't? Is it true if only ALL of them are true? Which is it exactly?

In your first example, you had a great clear expression. This one however, is not. That's why you're getting the suggestion to use `.all?` Because that's so much clearer on what you're trying to do, and of course will actually work (as opposed to this statement you have).